# Webpagetest open source, can both server and client be installed on a single linux server?

Tags: linux, webpagetest

Webpagetest offer a hosted service, but they dont support the countries I need to test.

I was going to setup WPT on a VPS linux server in the target country, but I cant find any installation instructions for the "client", only the server. There are some tutorials which use a local PC as a client, but this is not an option for us.

The question is can a linux server be both the server and client (so no other SW is needed) to test a page?

Comment: Why not try it out and see what happens? I don't see any general problem in your approach

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here:

https://github.com/WPO-Foundation/wptagent/blob/master/docs/install.md

It DOES support linux as agent (as well as server).